# UITable on a scrollView, UITable not acting on reloadData call

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, reloaddata

I've got a scroll view, with 2 UITables on it.
Everything about the table work well. Neither of the tables need to scroll themselves.
If I call

[self.tableOne reloadData]; when a button is pressed it works. But when I call it in a delegate method of UITextView it does not action. Is this some threading issue? Or what is causing this bizarre behavior.

I want to increase the size of a TableCell when the user presses on UITextView thats in each cell.

I added a NSLog here to confirm that this method is getting called.

```
 - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{ 
theTableCellCurrentlyBeingEdited = textView.tag;
[self.tableOne reloadData];  
}
```

Gets touched I note which cell is active, and call reload table so I can adjust the height of this cell in

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{   
if (theTableCellCurrentlyBeingEdited == indexPath.row)
{
    return 120;
}
else
{
    return TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT;
}
}
```

But heightForRowAtIndex never gets called.

I have tableOnes datasource and delegate set to self. 
In my .h I have added

```
<UITextViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

So the calls are getting here.

Anybody able to give me some advice as to what is going wrong?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Where do you call the text of the textView?
You are using `theTableCellCurrentlyBeingEdited = textView.tag;`
And the tag will not give you the text you entered. You are just changing the tag of your cell which won't change a thing to the visuals of the cell.

Second. Why not call:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

or

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

So that in the first delegate method your cell gets updated every char you write and in the second you are sure the user is done writing in the textview?

Comment: Hi Totumus, this is going way off the point. My concern is getting the table to reload when the user starts to edit in the UITextView. The reason I want to resize the table cell is so that the user can see the whole TextView while they type. Code for handling the text is not relevant to this problem, so for brevity and clarity I did not include it. Thanks for trying to help though, -Code

Comment: Alright, This tag contains the index of the cell? And it works as soon you pressed a button? Can you tell me what happens if you put the same code in the - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView method? This method gets called before the actual edit. 

Post the results please.

Comment: Totomus, putting the code into textViewShouldBeginEditing makes the reloadData method be acted upon. Thank you very much for the advice.